# Breaking Condition in If construct

Tags: tcl

Hi I am using this piece of code for inserting pipe in TCL. Can anybody please let me understand when this condition `[gets $pipe line] >= 0` fails.
For eg: only when `[gets $pipe line]` is a negative number this will fail.

In my case it is never returning a negative number and the TestEngine hangs forever

```
set pipeline [open "|Certify.exe filename" "r+"]
fileevent $pipeline readable [list handlePipeReadable $pipeline]
fconfigure $pipeline -blocking 0

proc handlePipeReadable {pipe} {
    if {[gets $pipe line] >= 0} {
        # Managed to actually read a line; stored in $line now
    } elseif {[eof $pipe]} {
        # Pipeline was closed; get exit code, etc.
        if {[catch {close $pipe} msg opt]} {
            set exitinfo [dict get $opt -errorcode]
        } else {
            # Successful termination
            set exitinfo ""
        }
        # Stop the waiting in [vwait], below
        set ::donepipe $pipe
    } else {
        puts ""
        # Partial read; things will be properly buffered up for now...
    }
}

vwait ::donepipe
```

Comment: Also posted vwait::donepipe at the bottom

Comment: I assume that certify program is text only. Does `set output [exec Certify.exe filename]; puts $output` provide the right output?

Comment: The `open |… r+` is a sign of danger. Bidirectional pipes have _lots_ more ways they can fail, such as the other side deciding to buffer longer than you want, or not producing any output until the input side is closed…

Comment: Hi Glenn,Here In the proc I have referred it as file name.But in our project, For the Certify(Tool) we will be passing a bunch of parameters to be able to trigger the script

Comment: In addition to this Glenn, When I use exec command to call an external process (Certify in my case), the TCL script(Test Engine) script hangs forever.Thats why, tried using a pipe

Comment: What does `Certify.exe` do? Could it be trying to read directly from the tty rather than stdin? Could it be waiting on some other external resource? Perhaps it's simply not designed to be run in a pipeline.

Comment: But it not working out with the help of the exec command either.is there any other way out to call this GUI based application??

Answer (score 1):

The `gets` command (when given a variable to receive the line) returns a negative number when it is in a minor error condition. There are two such conditions:

1. When the channel has reached end-of-file. *After* the `gets` the `eof` command (applied to the channel) will report a true value in this case.
2. When the channel is *blocked,* i.e., when it has *some* bytes but not a complete line (Tcl has internal buffering to handle this; you can get the number of pending bytes with `chan pending`). You only see this when the channel is in non-blocking mode (because otherwise the `gets` will wait indefinitely). In this case, the `fblocked` command (applied to the channel) will return true.

Major error conditions (such as the channel being closed) result in Tcl errors.

---

If the other command only produces partial output or does something weird with buffering, you can get an eternally blocked pipeline. It's more likely with a bidirectional pipe, such as you're using, as the `Certify` command is probably waiting for you to close the other end. Can you use it read-only? There are *many* complexities to interacting correctly with a process bidirectionally! (For example, you probably want to make the pipe's *output* buffering mode be unbuffered, `fconfigure $pipeline -buffering none`.)

Comment: Donal, Thanks for your reply. But I have already tried using fconfigure $pipeline -buffering none after fconfigure $pipeline -blocking 0 and in the proc as well. Still facing the same issue.Also tried to give the read only access for the pipe. No improvement on it. Can you please help me out

Comment: Yes, there are other things that can go wrong too. For example, the subprocess might detect that it is writing to a pipe and buffer its output; you have little control over that! Except… you can probably use `expect` (“probably” because of some Windows nuances). Which is _very_ different (despite being a Tcl extension), but can be used to automate problem programs. This all gets _a lot more complicated_ unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please convert my pipeline block to (spawn expect ) if that were to work???

Comment: Follow a _basic tutorial_ on using Expect, remembering to `spawn` the Certify executable instead of `exec`ing it. The code I wrote doesn't really convert over, _and doesn't need to:_ Expect does a lot more and works (from your perspective) at a much higher level.

Answer (score 1):

[image: CMD Prompt screen after running the test engine]

Please find the way the certify process is being triggered from the command prompt and the print statements are given just for the understanding. At the end the process hangs and the control is not transferred back to the TCL

Comment: Also this is the way I inserted a pipe in the test engine script to trigger the certify process:set pipeline [open "|Certify.exe $parameters(0) $parameters(1) $parameters(2) $parameters(3) $parameters(4) $parameters(5) $parameters(6) $parameters(7) $parameters(8) $parameters(9) $parameters(10) $parameters(11) $parameters(12) $parameters(13) $parameters(14) $parameters(15)" "r"].These are the bunch of parameters that need to be passed during Run-time.How can I use spawn-expect here??? Because when I use spawn instead of here, I am facing an issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time out to answer Bryan

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for gets](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/gets.htm):

> If varName is specified and an empty string is returned in varName because of end-of-file or because of insufficient data in nonblocking mode, then the return count is -1.

Comment: Can anyone please help me implement the pipe using spawn expect mechanism??

Answer (score 0):

Your script is working completely fine. checked with `set pipeline [open "|du /usr" "r+"]`
 instead of your pipe and included `puts "Line: $line"` to check the result. So its clear that there is some problem in `Certify` command. Can you share your command, how do you use on terminal and how did you use with `exec`?

```
################### edited by Drektz
set pipeline [open "|du /usr" "r+"]
fileevent $pipeline readable [list handlePipeReadable $pipeline]
fconfigure $pipeline -blocking 0

proc handlePipeReadable {pipe} {
    if {[gets $pipe line] >= 0} {
        # Managed to actually read a line; stored in $line now
################### included by Drektz
puts "Line: $line"
    } elseif {[eof $pipe]} {
        # Pipeline was closed; get exit code, etc.
        if {[catch {close $pipe} msg opt]} {
            set exitinfo [dict get $opt -errorcode]
        } else {
            # Successful termination
            set exitinfo ""
        }
        # Stop the waiting in [vwait], below
        set ::donepipe $pipe
    } else {
        puts ""
        # Partial read; things will be properly buffered up for now...
    }
}

vwait ::donepipe
```

Comment: Please find the image that I have posted Drektz, As you have said, I already tried this workaround as well

Comment: In the snapshot, I can see you have used `tclsh TestEngineSourceDepot.tcl` _(and I am assuming, in this file, pipeline is used, not exec)_, and it hangs for `TrialkillDLE`. Can you confirm that `Certify.exe` doesn't hang when you run it _standalone (ie not using tcl script, but directly as `Certify.exe $p0 $p1...$p15` on terminal) with the same parameters used in script_? One more thing, you can try `exec Certify.exe $p0 $p1...$p15 &` as this will run it in background so you will get the control back to Tcl.

Comment: Even when I am using the exec command I am facing the same issue. I have already tried it out . Then implemented the pipe mechanism.

Comment: `exec` **in background** using **&** ie `exec cmd args &` will back to your script irrespective of result.

Comment: Tried this as well.Still facing the same issue.But on the contrary when I am just using Certify.exe args in the command prompt the control is coming out.

Comment: Upon using exec cmd args in tclsh, facing the issue

Comment: I know you tried `exec cmd args` and this won't run command in background. To run in background, you need to append `&` and your command will be `exec cmd args &`

Comment: I did that Mr Drektz,still Iam facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

you can see it in the CMDwith& screenshot mentioned.Is there any workaround that I have to overcome the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please see the issue when run with the help of exec executable args &